# Hana Regular Expression is not working as expected

Tags: sql, regex, database, hana

We are using LIKE_REGEXPR in Hana to find records which have invalid characters. For instance, the value that I have in Address2 is

```
 JALAN*# CHANGKAT
```

`*` is not on my allowed list so my query should show the record. But it's not working as expected.

Code:

```
select *
from contact PRD
WHERE adress = 'Home' AND
      (prd.Address2 is null or  
       PRD.Address2 LIKE_REGEXPR '[^[:alnum:][:space:]_#&-/.,():{}_\!;$'']');
```

But it's not showing `JALAN*# CHANGKAT`. What is wrong with the query?

Comment: You need to explain what you want the regular expression to do.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I guess OP wants to say if `JALAN*# CHANGKAT` is stored on the table, REGULAR EXPRESSION should have this record in selection.

Answer (score 1):

You have included the character '.' in your RegEx - this would normally match **any** character.  You should escape any 'special' characters in your RegEx.

I recommend you test your regular expression in a RegEx tester (there are lots available online) to see if it giving you what you want.  Check the results yourself but I expect you need:

```regex
NOT LIKE_REGEXPR '^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t_#&\-\/\.,\(\):\{\}_\\!;]+$'
```

This finds entries that don't match the RegEx which matches the whole value (enclosed by ^ and $) to one or more of the characters in your list.  If you have a minimum length you can include that too, for example for a minimum of 8 characters you could use:

```regex
NOT LIKE_REGEXPR '^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\t_#&\-\/\.,\(\):\{\}_\\!;]{8,}$'
```

[Test your RegEx!!](https://regex101.com/)